# Angular 8: Scroll spy implementation for a timeline Contents

Tags: event-handling, dom, typescript, angular-2+

I have made a timeline component that can have multiple milestone/major/minor as sub components nested within timeline container component. I have also added a side navigation for that lists all Milestones. Therefore I append `range` property to `TimelineMilestoneComponent` which contains the top position `value(offestTop)` of its and consecutive element. like below

```
arr[i + 1] ? arr[i + 1].htmlEl.offsetTop - 1 : Infinity
```

Scroll Listener checks scroll position with with range values to decide if that is current viewed milestone.

**Is the implementation correct? 
What is better way of accomplishing this?**

[image: Rendered component]

Here is the component Class

```
export class TimelineComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  milestones: Array<ExtendedTimelineMilestoneComponent>;
  visbleMilestone: ExtendedTimelineMilestoneComponent;

  @Input()
  themeColor = "#254267";

  @HostBinding("attr.style")
  public get valueAsStyle(): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(
      `--theme-color: ${this.themeColor}`
    );
  }

  @HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event.target"])
  public scrollListener(doc: HTMLDocument): void {
    //avoid update visbleMilestone if scroll is within its scope
    if (
      window.scrollY < this.visbleMilestone.range[0] &&
      window.scrollY > this.visbleMilestone.range[1]
    ) {} else {
      this.milestones.every(m => {
        if (window.scrollY >= m.range[0] && window.scrollY < m.range[1]) {
          this.visbleMilestone = m;
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
    }

  }

  @ContentChildren(TimelineMilestoneComponent)
  set _milestones(milestones: QueryList<TimelineMilestoneComponent>) {

    this.milestones = milestones.map((m, i, arr) =>
      Object.assign(m, {
        range: [
          m.htmlEl.offsetTop,
          arr[i + 1] ? arr[i + 1].htmlEl.offsetTop - 1 : Infinity
        ],
      })
    );
  }

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.visbleMilestone = this.milestones[0] ? this.milestones[0] : null;
  }

  scrollToMilestone(m: TimelineMilestoneComponent) {
    m.htmlEl.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }
}
```